# View uploaded video in iOS app

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have a bunch of videos uploaded to google drive. They are in mpeg4 (avi) format I believe. I have tried everything I can think to view the video in a MPMoviePlayerViewController. In the simulator the video player launches and looks like it playing, but I don't see any video. When I run it on my device the player won't launch. I have tried to use the downloadUrl, alternateLink, embedLink and webContentLink with no success.

Is it possible to stream video from Google Drive to iOS?

Comment: I m trying to play video from google drive but all link u mentioned above are asking for Sign in. Than how can u Play from Google Drive..plz reply

Comment: you can stream mp4 videos from google without having to download them.
Pass this url to the movie player and it should stream the video
[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@&access_token=%@",downloadUrl,accessToken];   

you can fetch the access token from the GTMOAuth2Authentication object

Note that you might need to refresh it if its expires.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator isn't a full blown emulator, but just a simulator. It uses similar frameworks from Mac OS, which may have different functionality than on iOS. In other words, the simulator may have more capabilities than an actual device.

The [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class on iOS supports only a few containers and codecs, and does not support AVI.

> Supported Formats
>
> This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This
>   includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie
>   files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4,
>   .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:
>
> H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
>
> MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
>
> If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen
>   with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this
>   class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio
>   Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.